# Is it Possible to Place Property Files Relative to Server Path

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6, cas

I am attempting to place the 'cas.properties' file outside of the 'webapps' folder - but getting error listed in italics below. Is it possible to place the path relative to the server or only possible within the 'webapps' folder?

**Configuration for property file path:**

**Error in 'catalina.out':**
*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/home/tomcat/conf/cas.properties]*

Comment: Depends on how you're defining where the properties file is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - my bad.

Declare path as such:

file:/home/tomcat/conf/cas.properties

Answer (score 0):

You want a file located in a folder outside of your web application to be on the classpath of the application. The answer to your question depends on the used servlet container. In your case you use tomcat: Open [CATALINA_HOME]/conf/catalina.properties and add a the folder path under shared.loader (or common.loader).

Please note that this property file will then be accessible to all web applications deployed, and this could lead to some name collisions.